# Speeding up column conversions

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a large dataframe and that I want to apply one operation to every element in a column.

Is there a **faster** way of doing it than the following:

```
get_weekday = lambda x: time.strptime(str(x), '%d%m%Y').tm_wday
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(get_weekday)
```

?

Comment: When creating the DataFrame itself you could attempt to `parse_dates` and so you wouldn't have to do it later on, but in either case you pay the price at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In current master/0.15.0

```
df['date'].dt.weekday
```

In prior versions

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).weekday
```

Here's a timing example

```
In [16]: s = Series(date_range('20130101',freq='s',periods=100000))

In [17]: %timeit s.dt.weekday
10 loops, best of 3: 50.8 ms per loop

In [18]: s2 = s.apply(str)

In [19]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: time.strptime(str(x), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").tm_wday)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.65 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, does this assume that the input is already in `string` or perhaps in `datetieme` format?

Comment: yes, you should use ``to_datetime(...)`` if that's not the case. In general you *should* keep datetimelike in this format.